# React inline functions performance clarification

Tags: reactjs

Given this:
https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-bhaskara-1km1j

For `Child2` - why does it get re-rendered if i don't pass an inline function to it?

Would greatly appreciate some clarifications..

Comment: Not sure of you question, mind clarifying it with example code in your post here on what exactly you are trying to point at

Comment: @Rikin sorry, i edited my question. Basically - i thought that passing inline functions is what causes re-rendering, but that doesn't seem to be the case if you look at `Child2`. 

(Also following the topic from this thread about inline functions:
https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/9fp4oo/what_do_you_guys_think_about_inline_functions_in/
)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember `function` is being passed in as a value, so passing inline function to a component will only re-render if the value changes in this case function changes, which dont get redefined just on re-rendering. 
You are passing in function referenced by `this.clickMe` which gets defined once only upon `Parent` component initialization.

If you pass in a function that gets redefined in a `render()` method of `Parent`, your `Child2` component will re-render everytime as new function gets declared and passed upon every render cycle of `Parent`

Upon state change Parent re-renders thus it called Child1 and Child2 again and it re-rendered but the resulting DOM remained the same. You can prove that by changing DOM direct and see even though it re-rendered the DOM remained the same.

[image]

Here's a good read to understand rendering better: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/fix-the-slow-render-before-you-fix-the-re-render

Comment: But in my example, every time the Parent state changes, both Child1 and Child2 get rendered.. that's what i'm confused by.
I'm passing Child2 a function by reference, why would it re-render?

Comment: Yeah that's what I was confused in during my initial React days. Apparently that's where React diffing algorithm comes in play, it looks at the new render snapshot and old render snapshot and only changes what was changed. In this case Child component even though it was in new re-render cycle, the resulting object is still the same thus it dont get updated.

Comment: Sorry but i'm a bit confused still.. why is Child2 being re-rendered if nothing has changed in its props?

Comment: Parent re-rendered thus it called Child1 and Child2 again and it re-renderd but the resulting DOM remained the same.

Comment: So it doesn't matter if you use inline functions or not - as soon as you render the parent, all children get re-rendered? (given you're not using memoization)

Comment: Inline function will create new function everytime, so it does matter. Updated answer above, see if that clarifies

Comment: So inline function will create a new function every time (as opposed to a function that's passed by reference) but still, both Child1 and Child2 will re-render every time Parent's state is updated?

Comment: i updated my code.
If i manually update the DOM and change Parent's state, Child1 doesn't cause a DOM update. Why?

Answer (score -1):

It's because of the function pointer of `clickMe` changes every time parent `re-renders`. To avoid such unnecessary re-rendering you can change this line

```
export default Child2
```

to

```
export default React.memo(Child2)
```

Read more on memoization [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo).

Comment: I'm aware of memoization. But if the function isn't defined inline (like in the case of `Child2` - shouldn't it prevent `the Child component from being re-rendered?